# Can I point a domain to a specific folder in the host?

Tags: domains

let's assume I have two domains (one already set) and one host. I want to the second domain point to a specific folder in the host so that when you access `domain2.com` it points to `host/myfolder` so `domain2.com/foo.php` will be same as `host/myfolder/foo.php`. I hope it's clean. Is this possible?

Comment: What web server?? If Apache, you can simply set the DocumentRoot and <Directory> directives in the .conf file once a site is created.

Answer (score 1):

If you if you are using cpanel, it is trivial to do this.  Add the new domain as an addon domain and then point the document root to your new location.

Too avoid confusion, I strongly recommend that you make the directory of your new domain /host/domain2.com  so that if you add yet another domain you won't end up with a mess of confusing names.

A note of trivia: While your domain2.com/foo.php will work, so will domain1.com/domain2.com/foo.php as the second domain's folder will be sitting in the first domain's document root (assuming that is /home/user/public_html - which is the default)